# Update kube context using shell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to set the current context of the cluster using shell script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Set Parameters
echo ${cluster_arn}

  sh "aws eks update-kubeconfig --name abc-eks-cluster --role-arn ${cluster_arn} --alias abc-eks-cluster"

export k8s_host="$(kubectl config view --minify | grep server | cut -f 2- -d ":" | tr -d " ")"
```

However, the above command gives error:

> sh: 0: Can't open aws eks update-kubeconfig --name abc-eks-cluster --role-arn arn:aws:iam::4399999999873:role/abc-eks-cluster-cluster-admin --alias abc-eks-cluster

Can someone suggest me how do what is the issue and how can I set the current context because the k8_host command yiedls another error that context is not set.

Comment: some one did a tool for it, just use directly: https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you are even involving `sh` as a subshell, when you're already in a shell script, but

> Can someone suggest me ... what is the issue

You have provided the entire command to `sh` but failed to use the `-c` that informs it that the first argument is an inline shell snippet; otherwise, `sh` expects that the first non-option argument is a *file* which is why it says it cannot open a file with that horrifically long name

There are two outcomes to get out of this mess: use `-c` or stop trying to use a subshell

```sh
  sh -c "aws eks update-kubeconfig --name abc-eks-cluster --role-arn ${cluster_arn} --alias abc-eks-cluster"
```

or:

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name abc-eks-cluster --role-arn ${cluster_arn} --alias abc-eks-cluster
```